# R: Turn `c("a", "b", "c")` into `"'a', 'b', 'c'"`, where the number of elements within the vector is unknown

Tags: r, vector, stringr

I have a vector of unique characters (e.g. factor levels) of unknown length. I need to turn that vector into a single element with the following format using R:

`"'x', 'y', 'z'"`
 
There could be any number of elements combined but the last element cannot be followed by a comma and each element must be surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for any unique vector no matter what the length of this vector.

```
test <- c("x", "y", "z") 

paste0("'", test, "'", collapse = ", ")
# [1] "'x', 'y', 'z'"
```

Since you have the [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr) tag, here is a solution using the `str_c` function.

```
stringr::str_c("'", test, "'", collapse = ", ")
# [1] "'x', 'y', 'z'"
```